# Eclipse formatter is not strict?

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

I use this to set my maximum line width to 80:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.lineSplit=80
```

Let's face it, Eclipse's formatter is **not** strict.

It has a very high success rate, and format things very nicely indeed, but it is not 100% strict, sometimes it leaves lines > 80 characters and so it is useless for a project that just `lint`s and refuses code not *strictly* matching the 80 columns limit and requires Eclipse code auto-formatting.

These 2 things, Eclipse-based formatting and `lint`, can only really work together when the success rate is 100%. If not, even changing the code by hand triggers a "reformat/reflow" on save and the check-in bombs and refuses the commit.

I cannot disable the formatting on the client and I cannot circumvent the `lint`ing.

Is there *any* way at all to just make the wonderful Eclipse formatter 100% strict? Something like "`considerTheLimitSeriously=true`"?

Notice: it's eminently "unstrict" in lines with method signatures, but not only.

Comment: Have you tried find out why certain code was not formatted? What is the difference between  a formatted code and an unformatted code?

Comment: Is it auto-formatted on save, but the line it generates overflows the 80 columns limit. Other lines in the same file are just fine. High success rate but _not_ strict, which is making me waste the whole day today!

Comment: You should post an example line that the formatter isn't splitting. It is possible that there is no way to slit that line. It is possible that other formatter settings are conflicting with line limit. It is possible that there is a bug.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik: so you never saw Eclipse's code formatter "overflow"? Just wondering...

Comment: I tend to care about other formatting attributes over strict line limits. The important thing to understand is that the formatter rules are taken as a whole and line length limit is just one of the rules. Often, rules conflict. For instance, there is a "keep first method parameter on same line as method name" rule. Clearly, if the method name and/or parameter name is long enough, they can blow through the line length limit. If line length limit is the most important aspect, you need to find cases where you aren't getting the results you want and disable conflicting rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there's no way to make the formatter 100% strict when it comes to line splitting.  According to [JLS 3.8. Identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.

So it's possible that some lines *cannot* be split without causing a compile error.

The best you can do is set the formatting as strict as possible, then look at specific lines in your code to see where this is failing.  On the Eclipse main menu go to Window > Preferences, then go to the Java > Code Style > Formatter tab, then click Edit.  There you'll find a Line Wrapping tab where you can customize the line wrapping rules.